# return both created and existing file when adding to SRC in gulp task

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I'm trying to add a new file to the SRC stream and still keep the old file. but I think I can only return one file from through.obj().

**TestTask**:

```
function TestTask() {
    const rename = require("gulp-rename");
    const add = require("gulp-add");

    return src("Test/In/**/*.scss")
        .pipe(processStyleImportFiles())
        .pipe(debug());
}
```

**processStyleImport**:
    const processStyleImportFiles = () => {
        const through = require("through2");

```
    return through.obj((file, encoding, cb) => {
        if (file.basename.startsWith("_")) {
            var importFile = file.clone();

            importFile.basename = file.dirname + "." + file.basename.slice(1);
            importFile.base = "In/";
            importFile.contents = Buffer.from("Hey ya!"); //Buffer.from("@import \"${util.capitalize(file.dirname)}${\\}${filename.replace('.scss', '')}\"");

            cb(null, importFile);
        }
    })
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed the design and used gulp-foreach instead. Now I get both the new file and the original file in the stream.

```
function TestTask() {
    const foreach = require("gulp-foreach");
    const vinyl = require("vinyl");

    return src("Test/In/**/*.scss")     
        .pipe(foreach((stream, source) => {
            var dirname = source.dirname.slice(source.dirname.lastIndexOf("\\") + 1);
            var path = "Test/Out/" + dirname + "." + source.basename.slice(1);
            var content = "@import \"" + dirname + "//" + source.basename.slice(0, source.basename.lastIndexOf(".")) + "\"";
            var file = new vinyl({ path: path, base: "Test/Out", contents: Buffer.from(content) });

            stream.push(file);

            return stream;
        }))
        .pipe(debug())
        .pipe(dest("Test/Out"));
}
```